# Import collection to mongodb server from gmaps library in python

Tags: python, mongodb, google-maps-api-3, pymongo, mlab

I'm using python and i'm try to import a JSON like i'm recieving from this code:

```
from gmaps import Geocoding
api = Geocoding(api_key='<my key>')
api.geocode("calle tigre 129 cusco")
```

to mongodb server, like I created a collection with this code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('mongodb://<user>:<pass>@ds049219.mongolab.com:49219/<__>')

db = client.<__>
posts = db.post
post = [{'name': 'Joy', 'food': 'pasta'}, {'name': 'Hant', 'food': 'pizza', 'location': 'Holland'}, {'name': 'Jim', 'food': 'meat'}]

id_<__>s= posts.insert(post)
print 'create the id: %s'%post
client.close()
```

So I wrote that code:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
from gmaps import Geocoding

api = Geocoding(api_key='<my key>')
api.geocode("calle tigre 129 cusco")

client2 =  MongoClient('mongodb://<user>:<pass>@ds049219.mongolab.com:49219/<__>')
db = client2.<__>
apis = db.api
api = [{"calle tigre 129 cusco"}]

maps_<__> = apis.insert(api)
print 'create the maps: %s'%api

client2.close()
```

What I did wrong in the last code?

Thank you

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: The python wrote:
'set' object does not support item assignment

Comment: and:
 ---> 13 maps_<__>= apis.insert(api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line here:

```
api = [{"calle tigre 129 cusco"}]
```

{"calle tigre 129 cusco"} creates a set:

```
>>> {"calle tigre 129 cusco"}
set(['calle tigre 129 cusco'])
```

PyMongo expects a python dict. So you want something like this:

```
api = [{"address": "calle tigre 129 cusco"}]
```